# Laravel v5.2.31 Storage::exists('/') returns FALSE

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

in v5.2.27 it returned TRUE

Is it a bug or some desired change in behavior? I expect TRUE to be correct, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out this change comes from league/flysystem, since 1.0.21 it returns FALSE on `->has('/')`, before it returned TRUE .. which is what I would expect to see, same as `file_exists('/')` returns TRUE

Answer (score 0):

`Storage::exists()` method check for given file i.e. `/path/filename` and as you are not passing any file it seems working as expected.